# Adding decimals together using buttons

Tags: c#, pos

I am creating a POS system using windows forms for a school project and would like to be able to add decimals together using the code in a button and come up with a total as the output at the end... any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: `var result = myLovelyDecimnal + anotherAwesomeDecimal` now if this doesn't answer your question, you will need to add the appropriate information so that we can work out where you are at, and what you are trying to achieve. Unfortunately your description thus-far is lacking... a lot...

Comment: Question is too vague. Just sum up what you want in the button click event. Let us know what you tried and what issue you have.

Comment: basically in the button event i want to add a decimal to an undefined length array. Then at the end of the 'order' i would like to be able to sum the array and get the decimal output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If following doesn't answer your questions, please edit your post by elaborating your question.

Two questions I get so far.

1. Add a decimal to an undetermined length array.

Generally using `List` in C# if data keeps growing.

```
// Put this as your member variable
List<decimal> m_ItemPriceInOrder = new List<decimal>;

// In your button event
decimal price = ... // Get your price of item
m_ItemPriceInOrder.Add( price );
```

2. To sum up cost of items when checkout.

Using `foreach` to iterate through every item in your list.
Also a simple `for` loop is okay, but foreach represents "iterating through every item".

```
decimal sum = 0;
foreach( var item in m_ItemPriceInOrder ){
    sum+=item;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this comment it has helped me greatly and has done the exact thing that i need.

Comment: @InhXil You may elaborate on your details for your question. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).